# Localize ASP.NET WebForm Application using resources files

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, localization, resources

I have ASP.NET WebForms application c# based.

I have input text

```
<input type="text" id="txtUsername" name="username" runat="server"
       placeholder="<%$ Resources:Resource, Username %>" />
```

and a label

```
<label for="Username"><%= Resources.Resource.Username%></label>
```

also i create 2 resources files **Resource.resx** and **Resource.en-GB.resx** under **App_GlobalResources**

**Resource.resx:**

Username: username

**Resource.en-GB.resx:**

Username: email

When user switch between languages i used the following code

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo(code);
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(code);
Resources.Resource.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(code);
```

and the code will equal **en** or **en-GB** depending on the user selection.

**Problem:**

When we run the project and the code = **en-GB**, the label resources appears as  **Resource.en-GB.resx (email)** while place holder as **Resource.resx (username)**.

That's mean **<%= Resources.Resource.Username%>** works perfect, while changing the culture doesn't change the **<%$ Resources:Resource, Username %>**.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "code" variable in your code is the culture code:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(code);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(code);
```

hope this helps!